# Solr: Facet counts indexes cannot be strings?

Tags: string, solr, facet

When creating a list of facet values, I have this in my schema:

```
<field name="contract_facet_sector_ids" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" required="false" />
```

The facets I want to store are strings like "1_1", "2_43", "2_99", etc. However, when I view the facet counts returned data, the underscore seems to have been removed:

```
[facet_fields] => Array
        (
            [contract_facet_sector_ids] => Array
                (
                    [11] => 0
                    [243] => 0
                    [299] => 0
```

Could someone please help me with where I'm going wrong here? The definition of the "text" field type is as follows:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" 
            generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" 
            catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" 
            catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt" />
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" 
            generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" 
            catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" 
            catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Many thanks in advance!

Seb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [WordDelimiterFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory) is causing your underscores to be removed. Based on the following:

> Splits words into subwords and performs optional transformations on
>   subword groups. By default, words are split into subwords with the
>   following rules:
>
> split on intra-word delimiters (all non alpha-numeric characters).
>   "Wi-Fi" -> "Wi", "Fi"
>
> ...

Based on the description of how you are using this field - *"The facets I want to store are strings..."*. I would suggest that you use fieldType of `string` as defined below (from the Solr example), unless you really need the additional analyzers to be applied.

```
<!-- The StrField type is not analyzed, but indexed/stored verbatim. -->
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
```

Comment: Excellent. I will re-build my index using a "string" type for this field. Thank you very much indeed everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Solr's Analysis page will show you how your text get analyzed during the different steps

Comment: Ah yes, quite right, I should have done that first - my apologies; it's been a long time since I've used Solr.